# Dynamic css and javascript submitting to mysql database with php

Tags: javascript, php, css, dynamic

I have a choice between using Adobe Flash or to use javascript to create a dynamic bowstring website. How can I create the color which are selected to be submitted to a MySql by using PHP?

```
<html>
<head>
<TITLE>Cool Javascript</title>
<style>
body {
      background-color: linen;
      margin: 0;
}

    #blueDiv {
        position: absolute;
        top: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;          
      }
    #yellowDiv {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
        background-color: yellow;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;  
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="blue()"> blue button </button>

<button onclick="yellow()"> yellow button </button>
    <div id="blueDiv">
    </div>
    <script>
        var div = document.getElementById('blueDiv');
        function blue() {
            div.setAttribute("id", "blueDiv");
            }
        function yellow() {
            div.setAttribute("id", "yellowDiv");
            }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I might need to consider using images in my css script. 
Please advice on the above as I have been stuck with this for quite a few months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you save the clicked button's color to the hidden input:

```js
var colorsToBeSelected = document.querySelectorAll('.color-selector');
var selected = document.getElementById('selected');
colorsToBeSelected.forEach(color => {
 color.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   selected.value = window.getComputedStyle(color).getPropertyValue('background');
   console.log(selected.value, 'was selected');
 });
});
```

```css
.blue { background: blue; }
.yellow { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<button class="color-selector blue">blue button</button>
<button class="color-selector yellow">yellow button</button>
...
<input hidden type='text' id='selected' name='selected'/>
```

Everytime user clicks any of the colored buttons, it's background property is going to be stored in your inputs value. Background, as you mentioned images (*consider background-color for colors only*). On submission, it's going to be stored as `$_POST['selected']`, where `'selected'` is a value of input's `name` attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer wscourge. This will definitely be a great option.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but it returns "no Value".

Comment: I've looked into it and 'background' only was returning whole bg property, so in my fiddle i simply took first value with some string operations. 
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wscourge/1o0x7pqn/1/)

Comment: "I have created a form submit button but it submits the moment a color is selected. Let me quickly explain my problem... I am trying to create a bow string design with 2 or 3 different colors. This is what I have in mind: http://www.techwisecorp.co.za/bowstring.JPG If I just have colors of squares then it wont work. Thats why I wanted to include images. What do you think will be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

what about just use cookie ? like:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
} 

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
} 

function blue() {
    div.setAttribute("id", "blueDiv");
    setCookie('last-color', 'blue', 3);
}


function yellow() {
    div.setAttribute("id", "yellowDiv");
    setCookie('last-color', 'yellow', 3);
}

if(getCookie('last-color') == 'yellow'){
    yellow();
}
```

functions `setCookie` and `getCookie` are from: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I am just concerned that not all browsers has cookies enabled. If I could do something with a php session then it might help.

Comment: @Schalk then use ajax call, php will save last color to session and on outputting page content do something like: `if($_SESSION['last-color'] == 'yellow'){ echo '<script>yellow();</script>'; }`